# Redirecting command output in docker

Tags: linux, bash, logging, docker, output

I want to do some simple logging for my server which is a small Flask app running in a Docker container.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM dreen/flask
MAINTAINER dreen
WORKDIR /srv

# Get source
RUN mkdir -p /srv
COPY perfektimprezy.tar.gz /srv/perfektimprezy.tar.gz
RUN tar x -f perfektimprezy.tar.gz
RUN rm perfektimprezy.tar.gz

# Run server
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "index.py", "1>server.log", "2>server.log"]
```

As you can see on the last line I redirect stderr and stdout to a file. Now I run this container and shell into it

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 perfektimprezy
docker exec -it "... id of container ..." bash
```

And observe the following things:

The server is running and the website working

There is no `/srv/server.log`

`ps aux | grep python` yields:

```
root         1  1.6  3.2  54172 16240 ?        Ss   13:43   0:00 python index.py 1>server.log 2>server.log
root        12  1.9  3.3 130388 16740 ?        Sl   13:43   0:00 /usr/bin/python index.py 1>server.log 2>server.log
root        32  0.0  0.0   8860   388 ?        R+   13:43   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

But there are no logs... HOWEVER, if I `docker attach` to the container I can see the app generating output in the console.

How do I properly redirect stdout/err to a file when using Docker?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

When you specify a JSON list as `CMD` in a `Dockerfile`, it will not be executed in a shell, so the usual shell functions, like stdout and stderr redirection, won't work.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (`"`) around words not single-quotes (`'`).
>
> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo", "$HOME" ]`.

What your command actually does is **executing your `index.py` script and passing the strings `"1>server.log"` and `"2>server.log"` as command-line arguments into that python script**.

Use one of the following instead (both should work):

1. `CMD "python index.py > server.log 2>&1"`
2. `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "python index.py > server.log 2>&1"]`

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) recommends using the `exec` shell built-in in order to have the containers honor the OS signals and `docker stop`. So the first command becomes: `CMD exec python index.py > server.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 35):

To use `docker run` in a shell pipeline or under shell redirection, making `run` accept stdin and output to stdout and stderr appropriately, use this incantation:

```
docker run -i --log-driver=none -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr ...
```

e.g. to run the `alpine` image and execute the UNIX command `cat` in the contained environment:

```
echo "This was piped into docker" |
  docker run -i --log-driver=none -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr \
    alpine cat - |
  xargs echo This is coming out of docker:
```

emits:

```
This is coming out of docker: This was piped into docker
```

Comment: -d and -a do not go together

Answer (score 23):

Just a complement, when using **docker-compose**, you could also try:

`command: bash -c "script_or_command > /path/to/log/command.log 2>&1"`

Comment: Did you try it? This makes perfect sense to me, and doesn't work! So far I have been completely unsuccessful redirecting stderr to stdout when using a docker-compose `command` directive. stdout comes through fine.

Comment: Ah, my problem turns out to be that I needed to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable or run python with the `-u` flag, as this explains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24183941/562883

Comment: I had to get the pg_dump of my postgres container into a file on the host. Here is what I did: 

`docker run -ti -v /usr/local/jay/words_data:/mnt/data --rm --link mypostgres:pghost postgres bash -c "pg_dump -h pghost -U app_user myschema >> /mnt/data/export.sql"`

(sidenote: I could have used the simpler option -f with pg_dump, but it didn't occur to me at the time. Anyway, this answer helped me.)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["-u", "-m", "swagger_server"]
```

The "-u" is the key :)

Comment: [`-u`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) : "Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered."