# Docker: How to use redirect (command >> file.txt) from CMD[]?

Tags: unix, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to run a Django development server and log all output to file.

My Dockerfile executes the following command:

```
CMD ["/srv/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:3000", ">>", "django.log"]
```

It builds fine but crashes at run.

**Question:** How can I redirect output from CMD command to a file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting command output in docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo", "$HOME" ]`.

What your command actually does is passes the arguments `"0.0.0.0:3000"`, `">>"` and `"django.log"` to `"/srv/manage.py"`. What you actually need is

```
CMD "/srv/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000 >> django.log"
```

(or)

```
CMD ["/srv/manage.py", "runserver 0.0.0.0:3000 >> django.log"]
```