# How to save node-red console logs into a separate log file within docker

Tags: logging, docker, node-red

I have a docker instance of node-red and I want to save node-red console logs into a separate log file inside the docker container. Is there any method to do it?

Comment: It's very hard to answer this without knowing how you're starting node-red in the docker container

Comment: i am starting node-red in docker by using kubernetes. Can i be able to save node-red logs in the container ?

Comment: That is how you are starting the container, not how you are starting Node-RED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Node-RED process only logs to console at the moment, but you can redirect the output to a file using normal unix redirects e.g.

```
node-red > /path/to/log/file
```

The Node-RED service on Raspbian uses systemd to redirect the output to syslog with the identifier "Node-RED" so this could also be directed to a separate file.

The standard Node-RED docker containers just start Node-RED as the CMD. You can configure how docker logs that content using the details in the docker docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#configure-the-logging-driver-for-a-container.

If you want to modify the CMD to redirect the outut to somewhere inside the container then this SO question and answer will probably be useful: [Redirecting command output in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker)

Comment: node-red > /path/to/log/file
worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Using nodered.service for autostart you can uncomment parameter **StandardOutput=syslog** and all logs will be direct into /var/log/syslog file.