# VSTS - Docker / Container Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

As part of the build process I'd like to run some security checks.

I have the security tools and config stored in a Docker container, as part of the build I'd like to run this container and gather the results (exit code).

I've managed to do this with Jenkins but can't seem to figure out how it's done on Azure VSTS.

I've had a play around with Azure container services and registry with the VSTS docker plugin but still no joy.

Any ideas or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you doing this in Jenkins?  docker run should be docker run pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A way is that you can fetch the logs of a container through [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command.

Another way is that you can output the result to a file and access the data from that file. [A similar thread: Redirecting command output in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker).