# Dockerfile hide output of RUN command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I have a few `RUN` commands in my Dockerfile, how can I have it not print any output from a specific command, such as ignoring the printed statements from an `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN which nano || echo no nano
RUN bash -c "apt-get update &> /dev/null"
RUN bash -c "apt-get install nano &> /dev/null"
RUN which nano
```

(really got the solution from [Redirecting command output in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker))