# Custom docker run output in detached mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I just wondering if it was possible to print Dockerfile's CMD output when I run **docker run ...**.

I setup jenkins on an image and it would be convenient to have the defautl admin password displayed directly when running the image. Here is what I have in mind :

```sh
# Dockerfile

...
RUN systemctl enable jenkins
CMD ["/usr/bin/systemctl", "start", "jenkins"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/echo", "Jenkins default password : "]
CMD ["/usr/bin/cat", "/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword"]
```

I have tried to follow this post but I may not understand the solution:

[Redirecting command output in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker)

My desired output would look like this:

```sh
$ docker run -tid auto-server:1.0
c93f26eb1756ce98332a9be8dd88a824e65ab9c1342df762c8a62b9d62c13dcc
Jenkins default password : 
<the-jenkins-password>
$
```

And above all I wonder if this follows docker's good practices.

UPDATE

```sh
# output when I only keep CMD ["/usr/bin/systemctl", "start", "jenkins"]

$ docker logs auto-server
jenkins: Correct java version found
jenkins:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
jenkins:    ...done.

$ docker exec -ti auto-server bash
root@42dbec3a6eaa:/home/ubuntu# systemctl status jenkins
jenkins.service - Controls Jenkins Automation Server
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins, disabled)
    Active: active (running)
root@42dbec3a6eaa:/home/ubuntu#
```

Comment: One approach is to use `docker exec` once the container is running.

Comment: yes, that is what i use to do but maybe I can save one command to run

Comment: A container only runs one `CMD`; the last `CMD` wins.  If you need to run multiple commands, you need a shell script to be the `CMD`.  Usually you will want that `CMD` to run the single container process (Jenkins) as a foreground process.  To a first approximation `systemctl` doesn't work in Docker at all.  You can use `docker logs` to see what a background container has printed out, or inject the password yourself using a `docker run -v` bind mount.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using a script. Apparently, systemctl runs well jenkins in background (see my update)