# Ansible Docker MySql dump

Tags: mysql, docker, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible and docker to take a backup of my MySQL database. This is my ansible-task:

```yaml
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ mysql_dump_container_name }}"
    image: mysql:8.0.20
    env:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "{{ mysql_password }}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "{{ mysql_database }}"
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    volumes:
      - "{{ mysql_backup_dir }}:/backup"
    entrypoint: "mysqldump -u {{ mysql_username }} -p{{ mysql_password }} --host {{ mysql_host }} {{ mysql_database }} > 1.sql "
    detach: yes
    restart_policy: "unless-stopped"
  become: yes
```

I am getting the following error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

Entrypoint message is:

```
"entrypoint": [
    "mysqldump -u root -proot --host wl.cs.net TEST > 1.sql"
],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker for why it cannot work at all when specified in the exec form.... and I still have a doubt it can work at all on an ENTRYPOINT....

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't need to overwrite the `entrypoint` as the one that is already in the container will run your command. You just need to make sure that the `>` ends up at the right place. I do that by quoting the command.
You can do this:

```yaml
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ mysql_dump_container_name }}"
    image: "mysql:8.0.20"
    volumes:
      - "{{ mysql_backup_dir }}:/backup"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'mysqldump -u {{ mysql_username }} -p{{ mysql_password }} --host {{ mysql_host }} {{ mysql_database }} > /backup/1.sql'"
    detach: false
    cleanup: true
  become: yes
```

Additional notes:

- You do not need any `port` as the container is not listening for anything.
- You don't need the `env`, as you aren't creating a database.
- You probably want to write the dump to a file in `/backup`.
- You probably don't want `restart_policy: "unless-stopped"` as it doesn't make sense to restart a failed backup, as it will probably fail again. (You need to find out why it failed, first)
- You will probably want `detach: false`, so ansible will wait for the container to finish and then show `failed` if the backup failed.
- You will probably want `cleanup: true`, so you don't need to clean up containers manually.

Links:

- [Documentation of the `docker_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html)
- [Redirecting command output in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632959/redirecting-command-output-in-docker)